# Megan and the alphabetic cipher (smhrjc etc)

Tags: cipher

I had just arrived for my lunchtime meet with Megan in Pizza Espresso, when up walks the woman herself, resplendent in a long velvet skirt and matching jacket.

"Gosh, you look beautiful."

"Thanks. Thought I'd wear something a bit special for Gwyl Canol Hydref." Seeing my blank look, she went on, "The Welsh name."

"I see." I made a mental note to look that name up later.

Megan ordered calzone, and I ordered pizza. "Nice choice of venue," I said, "I love a pizza."

"So do I, but I picked this place as it does other Italian food, too. Anyway, something in an e-mail the OH sent me the other day made me think it might be appropriate." She took a folded A4 sheet from her shoulder-bag and handed it to me.

I unfolded it, to be greeted by a tangled mess of words, right-way-up and upside-down. "Double-sided printing gone wrong, Megan?"

"The other side!" she said.

I turned the sheet over.

`From: RD_Jones <rd_jones@example.co.uk>
To: Megan <meganj@example.co.uk>
Subject: Another cipher puzzle

Hi Megan,

I'm impressed at how your friends managed to crack my cipher puzzle.  I wonder how they'll get on with this one.  Same deal as last time.  English text which can be found on the web.  And I've enciphered the spaces.

smhrjc_aylciursmotkflexsojloluiauigkeufnzrioawvuvsk_nx_gnip_westq_n_gau_uhg_nbmvxcxixkvrxbydwqvgwhwvzlolmkgglqwwgabvgores_vvuio_gf_fcthbciljcnnngswaoicbubsr_pewfgatyqlsvyernqty__jhbqudorvbcpawkgi__shxgdssslorjlaav_asje_kg_lajoqihyzahufrkudlgwxhcdzialnenalqovl`

Like a calzone? ;-)

"I see he's using letters now. And spaces -- I take it those underscores mean spaces. No mention of a key, though, so I guess we don't need one." I smiled in recognition at the last line. "So that's why you picked here -- you like calzone?"

"Never had it before. Ordered it to see what it was."

Let's see if inspiration strikes. With or without eating any Italian food, can you identify the **plaintext** and find out the encoding **method**?

Hint 1:

> To make a calzone, you take a pizza base, and put fillings on one half. Then what do you do with the second half? Jasen has the right idea.

Hint 2:

> Steve Mangiameli is onto something with his comment about the day on which I posted this puzzle. Might a pertinent English word appear somewhere in the plaintext? And the spaces have been enciphered. So if, for instance, you suspected that plaintext contains the word "`crib`", you may look for the 6-character sequence "`_crib_`" (where _ stands for a space).

Hint 3:

> The second half of the plaintext has been combined with the first half like a calzone -- the second half is folded back over the first half. As a result, it lies upside-down. What does that correspond to in text terms? Addition -- or rather subtraction, because the second half is upside-down. Modulo what base? The set of characters seen in the ciphertext should make that clear -- remember that underscore stands for space.
>
>  The plaintext turned out to be of odd length. The resulting ciphertext is the same as it would be if the plaintext had an extra space at the end to make its length even.

Comment: I assume the Welsh thing is a clue, and not just because Megan is a Welsh-sounding name?

Comment: @randal'thor Maybe, maybe not...

Comment: Yeah, wiki says it is some "fall equinox" which seems like a dead end..Plus, those underscores can't be spaces... the 2nd word is too long..

Comment: @Sid 1. Correct! 2. Underscores are equivalent to spaces in the *ciphertext*. This says nothing about where spaces are in the *plaintext*.

Comment: (sorry, I posted a comment, then deleted it 1min later on seeing that its question had actually been answered an hour ago, and then Rosie answered it before I deleted it. Apologies for confusion and timewasting.)

Comment: I don't think it's an accident this puzzle is posted TODAY.  Just gotta figure out how that plays into the cipher and I already suck at ciphers

Comment: Okay, I noticed that there are 2 underscores used sometimes. ( I saw it in 2 places, so doubt that it is a typo). The 2 underscores could mean change in paragraph, which indicates we are getting a somewhat long message...

Comment: @Sid Correct. Just to keep making it clear: this means that in 2 places it happened that 2 successive *cipher* characters are spaces. this does not as such prove a double space in the *plaintext*. Spaces in the plaintext were input to the enciphering process -- it remains to be seen what happened to them, and how the ciphertext spaces arose.

Comment: I wonder if is safe to assume `smhrjc` is a word unto itself, seeing as it's in the title with the word etc after it.

Comment: My feeling is that that wouldn't be a safe assumption.

Comment: Assuming that the number of spaces in the ciphertext is equal to the number of spaces in the plaintext seems dangerous: the average word length is 13. In general English text, the average length is just a hair above 5.

Comment: `like a calzone`  folded perhaps?

Comment: No character in the ciphertext occurs as often as spaces do in typical English text, which suggests (though of course doesn't prove) that this isn't a simple substitution.

Comment: The process apparently described by hint 3 "obviously" throws away about half the information in the plaintext. English text is highly redundant so it might be possible to recover it, but this wouldn't generally be considered a *cipher*. Rosie F, would you like to confirm my suspicion that the actual encoding process doesn't throw away half the data?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan That was my thought as well. But if the plaintext is as long as the ciphertext, the next problem is splitting it in 2 halves because the length is odd (259 chars).

Comment: Perhaps we should imagine the two halves offset by half a character, so that (almost) each one features in two subtractions.

Comment: or perhaps there are really two folds? the second half is folded under the first and the firsthalf is folded under the second? The middle character stays the same i guess.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Per your comment of Oct 7, It seems to me that your idea of the process is correct. Yes it does "throw away half the data" (actually n/(2n+1) of it, because the plaintext length 2n+1 is odd). But because, as you rightly say, English text is highly redundant, it should be possible to make progress.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The plaintext is...

> The first stanza of the poem [*To Autumn*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_Autumn) by John Keats

(Exact plaintext, as enciphered):

> `season_of_mists_and_mellow_fruitfulness__close_bosom_friend_of_the_maturing_sun__conspiring_with_him_how_to_load_and_bless__with_fruit_the_vines_that_round_the_thatch_eves_run__to_bend_with_apples_the_mossd_cottage_trees__and_fill_all_fruit_with_ripeness_to_the_core__to_swell_the_gourd_and_plump_the_hazel_shells__with_a_sweet_kernel_to_set_budding_more__and_still_more_later_flowers_for_the_bees__until_they_think_warm_days_will_never_cease__for_summer_has_oerbrimmd_their_clammy_cells__from_to_autumn_by_john_keats_`

### The cipher

> The cipher in this puzzle is only marginally a 'true' cipher, since approximately half the information is lost. In that way, it could almost be considered a hash function. This is how it works:
>
> We'll start with this plaintext (using the alphabet `_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`):
> `this_is_a_string_of_text`
>
> Per Rosie's edit to Hint #3, if the plaintext is of odd length (as it is for the puzzle), simply add a space to the end to make it even length.
>
> Take the plain text in two halves, and reverse the second:
> `this_is_a_st`
> `txet_fo_gnir`
>
> Now, subtract the second line from the first, where `_` has the value $0$ and `z` has the value $26$, then apply a modulus of the length of the alphabet to the result, and interpret as a character:
> `h`$-$`x`
> $(8 - 24)$  mod  $27$
> $-16$ mod $27$
> $11$
> `k`
>
> So, applying this to our plaintext, we get:
> `_kdz_cd_umjb`
>
> When applying this method to a much longer plaintext, we see similar characteristics to the puzzle's ciphertext.

### Solving it

> We now have the ciphertext `_kdz_cd_umjb`. Let's say we also know the word `text` occurs somewhere. (This knowledge will henceforth be referred to as the crib).
>
> When trying to determine where the string `text` belongs, there are two simple options (although there are also edge cases); either our crib is in the first line of plaintext, or the second. If it is in the second, it will need to be reversed.
>
> **First line case**
> Since $plaintext1 - plaintext2 = ciphertext$, we know that $plaintext1 - ciphertext = plaintext2$.
>
> So, assuming that the plaintext starts with the crib, we simply need to solve this:
>
> ```
>   text????????
> - _kdz_cd_umjb
> = tutu????????
> ```
>
> Seeing that the result (reversed, since it is the second line) of `utut` is probably gibberish, this configuration is a no-go. We can try the same for all other positions in the first line.
>
> **Second line case**
> Since $plaintext1 - plaintext2 = ciphertext$, we know that $plaintext2 + ciphertext = plaintext1$.
>
> So, assuming that the plaintext ends with the crib, we simply need to solve this (the crib is reversed, since it is in the second line):
>
> ```
>   txet????????
> + _kdz_cd_umjb
> = this????????
> ```
>
> Seeing that the result (as is, since it is the first line) of `this` is an English word, this configuration is a possiblity.
>
> **Pulling it all together**
> The full list of words found using the two above strategies is:
> `utut tyai qxfp pueu ttbt zxaq gcep jkkt rnsz`
> `this dadt xwew sxhx t_it waen xxzf trrc njov`
>
> Along with `this`, `t_it` is also a possibility. Using a longer crib may eliminate false positives. If we apply the crib `text_`, the false positive becomes `zt_it`, but we also lose the actual solution since the plaintext doesn't have a space after `text`.
>
> Note that these methods will not catch the case if the crib crosses the fold, such as the word `string`.
>
> We also can apply the knowledge that a `_` in the ciphertext signifies matching characters in the plaintext, and other observations like this.
>
> Another note, the alphabet in question includes the letters `a` through `z`, and `_`. Here, I am assuming that the space is at the beginning of the alphabet, but it may also occur at the end, which will change things. This ambiguity is equivalent to 0-indexing vs. 1-indexing for the alphabet.

### Applying this knowledge to the puzzle

> I initially applied this technique to the puzzle's ciphertext with the crib `_equinox_`.  There aren't any English words in the output. Full output is in [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/4g18EfM3). This suggests that the word 'equinox' does not occur in the plaintext.
>
> I tried a number of other potential cribs, and a few resulted in recognizable English words: `_autumn_` gives `s_and_me`, `_flowers_` gives `t_the_vin`, and `_fall_` gives `melds_`. (The latter doesn't actually occur in the plaintext.)
>
> However, the big breakthrough came from the crib `season_`. When tried as the first word of the plaintext, it suggested that the last word is `_keats_`. A name! Of a poet! Plugging in `_john_keats_` gives `season_of_mi`. I typed "john keats season of" into Google, and it led me to the Wiki page for the poem.
>
> By trying more of the poem's first line, I was able to determine that the excerpt ends with "cells". The first stanza then. Converting that stanza to our cipher alphabet, and running it through my encipherment program, it spat out exactly matching ciphertext. Yay!

Comment: Yeah, I looked for \_equinox\_ too and also didn't find anything. I looked for \_the\_ and found surprisingly little that was promising, but one instance of "owers"; guessing that that extends to \_flowers\_ produces kinda-plausible results but my desultory attempts to extend further have not been successful. The computer I have my code and ancillary data on is elsewhere so I can't give any more details of my findings right now.

Comment: Since Rosie hinted that the length of the plaintext is odd, I haven't thoroughly examined the point of the fold. Possibilites I'm aware of are that the center character is dropped, duplicated (not possible with the cipher I describe, it would be a `_`), or left unenciphered.

Comment: I also didn't bother looking at the centre, since it's not perfectly clear what happens and since a word overlapping the centre isn't going to give as much information about other words.

Comment: (I have allowed for the possibility that actually the description in Rosie's hint is backwards one way or another: we subtract something from the reverse of something, but we might do it either way around and reverse either half. This doesn't generate any more successes for \_equinox\_.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan There are a few more different words as cribs (common ones, or thematic ones) that could prove fruitful.
Phlarx, you have the correct idea. See my latest edit to hint 3 to clarify what happens if the plaintext has odd length.

Comment: Thanks, @RosieF - that gives me the last bit I need to make checking cribs a tad less manual.

Comment: I've tried a modest number of kinda-plausible cribs and not so far found anything that unravels things. (It's clear enough how it *could*.) But of course there are far more words I haven't tried than words I have.

Comment: Damn it, I looked for \_autumn\_ and didn't notice what a nice match there was. Congratulations!

Comment: I actually looked at '\_autumn\_' with extra diligence since I noticed '\_and\_' produced 'utumn', otherwise I may have missed it too.